# Jquery mobile search nearest restraunt

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am a bit new to jquery mobile I am working an a app which will find the nearest restraunt near the users position of gps. How should I approach & how to use google api for it.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps [place-search API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceSearchRequest) is your friend.

The **types** parameter will allow you to restrict results to those of type [restaurant](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/supported_types). 
In addition, the **radius** parameter allow you to specify maximum distance from a given location (in meters).

Something else that might be handy is the [distance matrix function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) that allows you to compute distance from one point to multiple locations as described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043668/android-map-apis/11043972#11043972).

Comment: What if I want to search for a specific place or places with respect to users position?

Comment: You'll need to acquire the user's current location via GPS or HTML geolocation. See: http://html5demos.com/geo/ You then enter the current location into the place-search API as well as the specific name or location that you are looking for into the keyword field.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives to Google:

- https://gist.github.com/2504683 ( Unofficial OpenTable API )
- http://blog.foursquare.com/2012/01/18/find-what-you%E2%80%99re-craving-and-check-out-the-menu-too/ ( FourSquare )
- http://openmenu.org/api/docs/restaurant.php ( OpenMenu )

HTML5 Geo location

- http://html5demos.com/geo
- http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

Comment: What if I want to search for a specific place or places with respect to users position?

Comment: http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/mihail_mateev/archive/2012/06/25/html-5-geolocation-with-infragistics-jquery-map.aspx